# Do you have an estimate of how many developers are using ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I'm speaking at RoboUniverse promoting it's merits tomorrow!)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250085/do-you-have-an-estimate-of-how-many-developers-are-using-ros?/) by [MelTorrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28804/meltorrie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-12-15**:
@ahendrix, to me, this is the only possible answer. why not make this comment an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be able to find what you're looking for in the community metrics: http://wiki.ros.org/Metrics

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2016-12-15**:
I've heard @Brian Gerkey use 100,000 as an estimate of total users.  This is consistent with downloads to unique IPs, and probably way more than the number of actual developers contributing to the code base.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-15**:
@Bill Smart: yes, that is a good estimate and I've heard Brian use that figure as well.